# Specifying Type Contraints on a Generic Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic collection based type that holds other generic types:

```
class Collection<T>
{
}

class ItemType<K>
{
}

Collection<ItemType<string>> c = new Collection<ItemType<string>>();
```

Is there a way to specify the constraints for `Collection<T>` such that `T` is an `ItemType` with any type `K`?  Sort of like this with fake syntax:

```
class Collection<T> where T : ItemType<>
{
}
```

Comment: updated my answer, I think the solution with the non-generic interface is what you are after

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yup

Depending on what you actually need, you can do:

```
  class Collection<T>{}
  class ItemTypeCollection<T> : Collection<ItemType<T>>{}
```

or

```
  class Collection<TContainer,TItem>
       where TContainer : ItemType<TItem>
  {

  }
```

Which one you choose depends on whether or not derivatives of `ItemType<T>` have different interfaces than `ItemType<T>`

There is one other approach as well that might work for you. But, it is a little bit more complicated.

You can create a non-generic base class or interface, such as `IItemType` and make the generic class `ItemType<T>` implement that non-generic `IItemType`.

Then you can write

```
 class Collection<T>
      where T: IItemType{}
```

Then, if your `IItemType` implementation is generic, you can create a `Collection<ItemType<T>>`. If you try to make a `Collection<T>` and `T` doesn't implement `IItemType`, then it will not compile

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class ItemTypeCollection<T, K> : Collection<T> where T : ItemType<K>
{
}
```